# \BibUrl based on \url command refuse take % symbol

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, urls

Can't figure out why `\BibUrl` command refuse take `%` symbol while `\url` does it. After all `\BibUrl` just call `\url`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\url{https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F}

%\providecommand*{\BibUrl}[1]{\url{#1}}
%\BibUrl{https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

%\url{https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F}

\providecommand*{\BibUrl}[1]{\url{#1}}
\BibUrl{https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are grabbing the argument before `\url` can do its work. Try `\providecommand*{\BibUrl}{\url}`

Comment: It works indeed. I use `.bst` file where `\BibUrl` command described as shown in my post and I can't typeset `URL's` with `%` symbols. Why this command described so?

Comment: No idea, ask the author of the bst.